# Help capturing attribute data-sort in a DIV as an array? Jquery/Javascript

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, javascript

The function I am using now is:

```
<div class='edit' data-sort='1'></div>
<div class='edit' data-sort='4'></div>
<div class='edit' data-sort='7'></div>

<div id="as"></div>




exist = $('.edit').length;

var valuer=new Array();


if(exist > 1) {
valuer = $('div[data-sort]').attr('data-sort');

$('#as').append(valuer);
}
```

But the array 'valuer' only captures the first value, appending the number 1 to the div '#as'

How can I capture all of the values, and then append them to the div '#as'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use the [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) for looping each HTML element found on your selector. Like:

```
// Edit
var list = [];

$('div[data-sort]').each(function(){
    // Append to #as
    $('#as').append($(this).attr('data-sort'));

    // Stores on list
    list.push(this);
});
```

Comment: would there be any way to display only one value? such as valuer[1]

Comment: I don't understand now. Can you explain me?

Comment: yes, I would like to create an array of the data-sort values, so I can access one value. So if there are 4 divs with the attribute data-sort, I would like to be able to access, for instance, the 4th using array[3]

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's map() function for this:

```
$('#as').append($('div[data-sort]').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('data-sort');
}).get().join(','));
```

The advantage of the map function is that you can also sort your values on the fly as you would any other JavaScript array. For example:

```
$('#as').append($('div[data-sort]').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('data-sort');
}).get().sort().join(','))
```

Comment: How would I create an array? So for instance if I would like to see what the value of array[2] would be? in my example it would return '7' because the 3rd objects data-sort attribute = 7

Comment: The `$.map()` function returns the set of selected elements or values as an array, so if you create a new variable, e.g. `var myDivs = $('div[data-sort]').map(function(){...});`, you can call `console.info(myDivs[2].attr('data-sort'))` to see the value.

Comment: Actually, that's all getting overly complicated. If you want an array of DOM elements, then you just define them as a jQuery call: `$('div[data-sort]')`. Or you'd get the second one in your group by calling `$('div[data-sort]')[2].attr('data-sort')`.